# Gradle Release plugin with Git submodules and Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, gradle, release, gradle-release-plugin

I have a problem when execute the Gradle Release plugin on Jenkins.

The project is a microservices achitecture with this folder structure:

```
root   
\- configserver
\- serviceregistry
\- authserver
\- service1
```

where each service is a git submodule.

Jenkins starts the release process when a new commit is pushed to root 'master' branch but the plugin failed the build because on the submodules the HEAD is detached. Searching other questions here, seems that the solution is to configure Jenkins to checkout the local branch but this not works with submodules.

Anyone have a solution for this?
Thanks!